# Full join ManyToMany field Django

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

all). I writing project using Django 2.0. I have 2 models: collaborator and department (1 collaborator can work in one or more departments). So, I want to query table such as:

```
|                | Department 1 | Department 2 | Department 3 |
|:---------------|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| Collaborator 1 |     True     |     False    |     False    |
| Collaborator 2 |     True     |     False    |     True     |
| Collaborator 3 |     True     |     True     |     True     |
```

- Collaborator contains `first_name` and `last_name`.
- True if collaborator works in this department.
- False if collaborator doesn't work in this department.

I want a minimum number of requests to the database and don't how is better: use raw/execute or other django-orm methods?

#### models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    """Model that represents department information."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Collaborator(models.Model):
    """Model that represents collaborator information."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - **prefetch_related**. It invokes only 2 queries, which is sufficient.

```
data_grid = {}
    for collab in Collaborator.objects.prefetch_related('departments'):
        full_name = f'{collab.first_name} {collab.last_name}'
        data_grid[full_name] = [depart.title for depart in collab.departments.all()]
```

So then the other filters will be done by the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a join table, I find very little advantage using manytomany, then you just query the join

```
class Department(models.Model):
    """Model that represents department information."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class DepartmentCollaboratorJoin(models.Model):
    """Model that represents join."""

    department = models.ForeignKey("Department")
    collaborator = models.ForeignKey("Collaborator")
    joininfo = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Collaborator(models.Model):
    """Model that represents collaborator information."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Comment: The `ManyToManyField` does this implicitly for you.